# How do I test an asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, qunit

I'm trying to test an ansynchronous callback by checking that it's called, say, `n` times in `m` seconds.

Here's my code so far:

```
test("async callback", function() {
    expect(1);
    var called = 0;

    var callback = function() {called++;};

    var model = new Model(callback);
    model.startCallbacks();

    function theTest() {         // call this a few seconds later and verify
        model.stopCallbacks();   //   that the callback has been called n times
        equal(3, called, "number of times callback was called");
    }

    setTimeout(theTest, 10000); // wait about 10 seconds until calling theTest
});
```

(`model.startCallbacks` and `model.stopCallbacks` are implemented with `setInterval`.)

This doesn't work.  I think it's because execution goes off the end of the test function while `callback` is still being asynchronously executed.

**What I want to test:** that `model` is correctly calling `callback`.  How do I do this?

Comment: I just needed to RTFM. How embarrassing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// use asyncTest instead of test
asyncTest("async callback", function() {
    expect(1);
    var called = 0;

    var callback = function() {called++;};

    var model = new Model(callback);
    model.startCallbacks();

    function theTest() {         // call this a few seconds later and verify
        model.stopCallbacks();   // that the callback has been called
        equal(3, called, "number of times callback was called");

        // THIS IS KEY: it "restarts" the test runner, saying
        // "OK I'm done waiting on async stuff, continue running tests"
        start();
    }

    setTimeout(theTest, 10000); // wait about 10 seconds until calling theTest
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the start and stop functions for asynchronous testing (see the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/stop)), example:

```
test("a test", function() {
  stop();
  $.getJSON("/someurl", function(result) {
    equal(result.value, "someExpectedValue");
    start();
  });
});
```

Your example would be:

```
test("async callback", function() {
    stop(1);
    var called = 0;

    var callback = function() {called++;};

    var model = new Model(callback);
    model.startCallbacks();

    function theTest() {         // call this a few seconds later and verify
        model.stopCallbacks();   //   that the callback has been called n times
        equal(3, called, "number of times callback was called");
        start();
    }

    setTimeout(theTest, 10000); // wait about 10 seconds until calling theTest
});
```

You can also use the shortcut [asyncTest](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest#nameexpectedtest).